# Understanding yield in kotlin sequence

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I understand that the kotlin `sequence` is just a coroutine with a `yield` suspend function (correct me if I'm wrong).
So the yield function sets the value and suspends the coroutine until the next value is requested.

`yield` source code

```
override suspend fun yield(value: T) {
    nextValue = value
    state = State_Ready
    return suspendCoroutineUninterceptedOrReturn { c ->
        nextStep = c
        COROUTINE_SUSPENDED
    }
}
```

[Link to kotlin source code github](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f3385fbdcb8b9dc29661a8a4973c855cdcf73767/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/SequenceBuilder.kt#L162-L169)

I see that it set the `nextValue` & `state` and suspends the coroutine by calling `suspendCoroutineUninterceptedOrReturn`.

**Now I would like to know, where does this get resume?**

I don't see any resume call inside `next()` function

```
override fun next(): T {
        when (state) {
            State_NotReady, State_ManyNotReady -> return nextNotReady()
            State_ManyReady -> {
                state = State_ManyNotReady
                return nextIterator!!.next()
            }
            State_Ready -> {
                state = State_NotReady
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                val result = nextValue as T
                nextValue = null
                return result
            }
            else -> throw exceptionalState()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just from looking at the source code page you linked:

Calling `next()` first checks if `hasNext()` has already been called. If it has, it can immediately return the next value, which was queued in `hasNext()`. If `hasNext()` has not yet been called, `nextNotReady()` is called, which basically calls `hasNext()` to prepare that next value and then returns it.

So the real work all happens in `hasNext()`. It checks if the current continuation’s iterator (which exists if `yieldAll()` is called) has another value, in which case it can queue it without resuming the continuation. But if the current iterator is done or there was no iterator, then it calls `resume` on the continuation, which makes it run until the next `yield()` or `yieldAll()` call.

This description is a big simplification. There are different edge cases that it is handling based on the order of next/hasNext calls.

Comment: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f3385fbdcb8b9dc29661a8a4973c855cdcf73767/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/SequenceBuilder.kt#L126 why they are setting the state to failed before resume

Comment: I think they are setting it as a default state so if there is an exceptional error before the next `yield` or `yieldAll` call, it will know to throw an exception itself on the next iteration.